# Display map annotations using State Variable properties

Tags: swiftui

Edited to show @Ashley Mills comments

I am creating an app which will display ice rinks on a map
I have followed a post about how to display a map with annotations. Full link is here : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-annotations-in-a-map-view

I am trying to add my own annotation (using the City Class for now)

I am receiving errors in the init function
Variable 'self.iceRink' used before being initialized,
Variable 'self.region' used before being initialized

My full code

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct IceRink: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
}

struct City: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct IceRinkView: View {
    @State private var iceRink: IceRink
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    private let annotations: [City]
    
    init(iceRink: IceRink) {
        self.iceRink = iceRink
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: iceRink.lat, longitude: iceRink.lng), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))
        
        annotations = [
                City(name: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275)),
                City(name: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508)),
                City(name: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5)),
                City(name: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667)),
                City(name:  iceRink.name, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: iceRink.lat, longitude: iceRink.lng))
            ]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(iceRink.name)
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotations) {
                MapPin(coordinate: $0.coordinate)
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
    }
}

struct IceRinkView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let iceRink = IceRink(name: "Cardiff", lat: 51.48439917004662, lng: -3.177987950883214)
        IceRinkView(iceRink: iceRink)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot showing error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the contents of `iceRink` before it's been initialised. What you could do is create a custom `init`:

```
struct IceRinkView: View {

    @State private var iceRink: IceRink
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    private let annotations: [City]
    
    init(iceRink: IceRink) {
        _iceRink = State(wrappedValue: iceRink)
        _region = State(wrappedValue: MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: iceRink.lat, longitude: iceRink.lng), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)))
        
        annotations = [
                City(name: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275)),
                City(name: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508)),
                City(name: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5)),
                City(name: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667)),
                City(name:  iceRink.name, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: iceRink.lat, longitude: iceRink.lng))
            ]
    }

    // etc
}
```

*However*, once you've initialised a view's State variable, it won't be reset during the lifetime of the view, so if you change `IceRink` in a containing view, the State in this view won't change. Your containing view should have the `@State var iceRink: IceRink`, and `IceRinkView` should have a Binding to it, for example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var iceRink: IceRink = // some ice rink
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Ice rink 1") {
                iceRink = // ice rink 1
            }
            Button("Ice rink 2") {
                iceRink = // ice rink 2
            }
            
            IceRinkView(iceRink: $iceRink)
        }
    }
}

struct IceRinkView: View {
    
    @Binding var iceRink: IceRink
    
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion {
        MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: iceRink.lat, longitude: iceRink.lng), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))
    }
    
    var annotations: [City] {
        [
            City(name: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275)),
            City(name: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508)),
            City(name: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5)),
            City(name: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667)),
            City(name:  iceRink.name, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: iceRink.lat, longitude: iceRink.lng))
        ]
    }
    
    // etc    
}
```

Comment: Thanks - It wont be a containing view, it will be called as destination view from a previous view. Using the first section of code,  I am still getting a similar error on the self.iceRink = iceRink and region lines : Variable 'self.iceRink' used before being initialized, Variable 'self.region' used before being initialized

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? The way you initialise a State variable has been simplified in Xcode 14

Comment: Just checked : 14.2

Comment: The code I give in the first example works perfectly for me (if I add a `body`). Have you tried it exactly as posted?

Comment: Yes - copied and pasted. I'm new to SO, am I able to post my code in a comment?

Comment: I have updated the question to show new full code and error

Comment: OK, thanks for the code. I've updated my answer to use `State(wrappedValue:)` , this should fix your problem